# gcloud saves logs line by line instead of saving the whole entry

Tags: node.js, gcloud

I use gcloud run to host my application, which in its turn saves the application logs and I can view them via the logger explorer.

however, it logs each line of the log as a separate log instead of saving the whole entry which decreases the readability

this happens whether the log is a multi-line plain text or a JSON object.

[image]

how can I configure my project or my gcloud account to properly save the application's logs

note that I don't add any snippet for gcloud logs in my project or made any configurations for it, I just run my app in gcloud run

Comment: Does your last statement mean you didn't explicitly include any logging commands (or print statements) in your code?

Comment: no, I didn't setup gcloud logging by myself, but it captures errors and console.log() outputs from my app because it hosted in gcloud run

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are describing. Each row in Cloud Logging is one line from your logs. You mention **each line of the log as a separate log**, I do not see that in your question.

Comment: What compute service are you using? It appears you're outputting to stdout|stderr, the Cloud Logging agent parses these files and adds a `LogEntry` per line. Stacktraces are generally output as multiline. To avoid this, I think (!?) you will need to tweak the log formatting in your code. See [Format errors in logs](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages)

Comment: I just use simple logging like `console.log()` and `console.error()` instead the uncaught exceptions from the application @DazWilkin

Comment: formatting errors seems to be a good point, but what exactly should I modify to format my logs?

Comment: I don't want to log each line, I want to log each multiline log as one entry for readability @ John Hanley

Comment: Please review the documentation in the link that I included. It explains how to solve the issue.

Comment: Edit your question and show the Cloud Logging interface that you implemented in your application. If you did not implement one, then you cannot change the format as each line written to stdout and stderr will result in one log entry.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. Any updates on this?